# (+/-) button did not work on modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to make a modal pop up which inside of it contain a (+/-) button, it's work if it's not inside the modal, but it doesn't work inside of the modal.

Here is my (+/-) code :

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    <button style="border: 1px solid #000000;padding: 2px;color: black" 
    class="incr-btn" data-action="decrease" href="#">-</button>

    <input id="number" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" 
    style="max-height: 29px;max-width: 15px; border: 1px solid #000000">

    <button style="border: 1px solid #000000;padding: 2px;color: black" 
    class="incr-btn" data-action="increase" href="#">+</button>
</div>
```

And here is my (+/-) js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(".incr-btn").on("click", function (e) {
    var $button = $(this);


var oldValue = $button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
    $button.parent().find('.incr-btn[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');
        if ($button.data('action') == "increase") {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
            // Don't allow decrementing below 1
            if (oldValue > 1) {
                var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
            } else {
                newVal = 1;
                $button.addClass('inactive');
            }
        }
        $button.parent().find('.quantity').val(newVal);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Format the code

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't know what you mean :/

Comment: I wanna see your html code of modal part. Can you post your html code?

Comment: it's too long, i added it here https://jsfiddle.net/j9udsup8/

Comment: sorry but, could you post more code to fiddle? I want to see how modal works. and please add `js` either.

Comment: sorry, i already add it now https://jsfiddle.net/j9udsup8/

Comment: what is the error? have u open the browser console to check? have you debug through whether the selector is correct? `incr-btn[data-action="decrease"]` ur jsfiddle is not complete, so it is hard to simulate it

Comment: the error is the increment and decrease button did not work :/ i already complete the jsfiddle i think :/ let me edit the fiddle with +/- button outside of the modal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j9udsup8/2/